# What happened to Snow?

Tags: kde

In Kubuntu 12.04 (and maybe 12.10, I think) there was a neat eyecandy effect you could enable in "Desktop Effects" under System Settings that made snow fall on the desktop. In 13.04, it isn't there!

Has it been dropped? For what reason is it not appearing?

It is/was an entertaining and visually useful desktop effect.

Comment: You should take a look at Xsnow: `sudo apt-get install xsnow` (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xsnow)

Comment: Thanks, looks like a cool program. However, when I run it with `xsnow`, nothing happens... ^.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When kwin was modified to use OpenGL ES, some effects had to be rewritten.  A couple of them ended up being dropped because nobody felt like porting them.

[Here's an article from Martin Gräßlin's blog](http://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2011/07/running-kwin-with-opengl-es-2-0/); in the comments he states that he is not planning on reimplementing the snow effect.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Glad to be using the most advanced (and one of the most actively developed) desktops out there!

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version of xsnow available on sourceforge:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xsnow/

From the website:

Finally, a working xsnow for Gnome, KDE, etc. Based on the original xsnow-1.42 created by Rick Jansen, after the xsnow-2019 conference in Antas (Spain) we now have available a xsnow that works on many desktop environments, even Raspian. By request of many beta-testers, a graphical front end has been created as well.